# How to work around the delayed/slow WebView rendering which occurs on some devices?

Tags: android, performance, webview, rendering

When utilizing a WebView to display simple formatted text (no remote content loading), some devices like the Nexus 4 or Galaxy Nexus have a very notable delay between onPageFinished() and actually displaying the text. If the WebView is used in a dynamic vertical layout with it's height set to wrap_content, all elements below will visibly *jump* down and hence create a very bad user experience.

For example:

```
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);
        WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webview.loadData("<html><head></head><body>WebView rendering is slow on some devices like the Nexus 4!</body></html>", "text/html", "utf-8");
    }
}
```

With `R.layout.activity_web_view` being

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#AAA" >

    <WebView android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/webview"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="Elements below the WebView are jumping down when rendering is completed."/>
</LinearLayout>
```

A demo project with this code can be found at https://github.com/rodja/webview-slow-rendering-demo

How can I best work around this issue? [Speed up tips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7422427/android-webview-slow) I found on StackOverflow seems not to help. Is hiding the whole LayoutGroup [until rendering is done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9828617/how-to-know-when-webview-rendering-is-finished) the only option?

Comment: Are you using Android 4.4? I'm experiencing that problem in all devices running KitKat.

Comment: did you resolve the slow rendering ?

Comment: What do you want to render? If it is simple HTML formatted text, there are other methods of doing this which are much faster. I can post an example.

Comment: I've not found a workaround so far. If you have examples to render simple HTML formatted text which do not have this problem I would be glad to see you posting an answer.