# Android webview loadData

Tags: android, webview, loaddata

I try to load a HTML page into an Android Webview using loadData function. The issue is that the first time I scroll down the view, it seems like is loading the HTML code. 
Is possible to load the HTML site completely before showing the webview?
Otherwise, this first time the view goes slowly down and blink a lot.
I'm getting this webview through a FragmentManager
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Local asset? or server rendering

Comment: You may refer the following link for help-

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16579248/how-to-work-around-the-delayed-slow-webview-rendering-which-occurs-on-some-devic

Comment: there is no answer for above link. Why you are posting waste link over  here :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to disable the hardware accelerator on the activity:

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```

Answer (score 1):

This may help :`myWebView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);`